# Cursor jumps above the element in ie9

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-3, internet-explorer, google-chrome

in my MVC3 application I'm switching the cursor when hovering above an -element.

Here's the javascript code:

```
$('#print').hover(function () {
    var cursorUrl = 'url(@Url.Content("~/Content/img/print_24.ico")), auto';
    $(this).css('cursor', cursorUrl);
});
```

The problem is: google chrome shows it the way it should be. The cursor hovers and the icon is shown on the mouseposition. But internet explorer shows the cursors icon 0,5 - 1cm above the  link. I've tested browsermodus IE7, IE8 and IE9. But the icon is always above the link.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this problem while using .cur cursor files (It gets correctly displayed in chrome and firefox too).

To create these cur files I've used [RealWorld Cursor Designer](http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-maker)